# Securely mounting a Samba share from a VPS on a local machine

Tags: security, ssh, samba

In my own little slice of the internet, I have a share that I want to serve up so I can mount it on my system at home and work with files as if they were local.  I have this setup as a Samba share at the moment.  However, I'm not entirely sure on how to go about keeping this setup secure.  What is the recommended way to secure this setup?

Right now I'm thinking to (obviously) require a username and password and open up the relevant ports, but how does one set this up so that the password isn't transmitted in the clear?  Is there something like a "Samba over SSH" protocol?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, OpenVPN. See Lucas' comment below. Note, however, you are now stepping off into deep water. Perhaps you should be doing this with an OS that you are already familiar or at least learn to swim before you venture out to play with the sharks.

Comment: Without explaining why this is "stepping off into deep water" this is kind of a useless comment.  What things should I be aware of?  I work with Linux on a daily basis.

Comment: If you don't know enough about networks to understand *just* how obvious the answer to your question really is, you're stepping off into far deeper waters than you realize.

Comment: Then I can learn...?  I thought that was the point of the Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use VPN over SSL/TLS. (openvpn)